# Ensuring that a path goes downhill

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, slope, cost-path

GIS student hoping for a bit of wisdom on the Path Distance tool.  I am doing a ski slope analysis, trying to find runs using cost grids (that incorporate slope, aspect, avalanche risk, etc.)  While I am familiar with the cost distance tool for finding the path of lowest cost, I wanted to see if there is a way to find paths that are: 1) of lowest "cost" in terms of my cost grid, 2) always sloping downhill (or at least remaining flat).  I have played with the path distance tool for a while now, and the documentation is limited.  Is this the right tool to use?  I've been setting the vertical factor parameters with my DEM to have a zero factor of 1, a low-cut angle of -90 degrees, and a high-cut angle of 0 degrees.  This produces a grid containing only one cell, with value 0.

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: I can only help with your 2nd q. Interpolate Shape (3d analyst required) to get Z for your lines. Export your line uphill ends and downhill ends using feature vertices to points (Start and End respectively, advanced license required), if your lines and thus points are 3d addXY will put the Z into the table for start and end points, then join the lines to the Start/End points. Lines where start.Z < end.Z will be flipped the wrong way. This method only checks the ends and will not tell you if the line goes over a hill in the middle... to check every vertex python or ArcObjects would be required.

Comment: Always tag ArcMap questions with [tag:arcgis-desktop] if you want them to reach that wide audience.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  If I understand your response correctly, you are suggesting that I create a spreadsheet giving the elevation value along each pixel of the ski run/path once a LCP has been created?  This I have done, and it does generally maintain a downward slope throughout the path.  However, I want to make sure that _every_ portion of the run goes downhill, not just that the general pattern is downhill.  Did I misunderstand your response or is there another way to achieve my goal?  Cheers.

Comment: I'd raise avalanche risk areas N meters above existing terrain and run hydrlogical analysis on it. Flow direction will give you what is called back-link in cost paths. Put any number of skiers on the top and run cost paths. skiing

Comment: I afraid that most of your route will eventually run along avalanche prone areas

Comment: I said nothing about a spreadsheet - yuk! No what I mean is that in python or ArcObjects you can read every geometry down to the vertex level and cycle through them in order from start to end and do *something* if the previous Z is less than the current vertex Z. I have written a tool for this for finding drainage that flows uphill at any point; if you have any coding ability I'm happy to share source but can't give the compiled tool to you as it's part of a toolbox which contains tools that I wont share.

Comment: If you don't want skiers to go into avalance areas, through fences or over cliffs then mask http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000 them out of your raster before following @FelixIP comment on hydrological flow path. Create a big polygon covering your analysis area and cut holes out for 'no-go' zones.

Comment: Did you get a solution to finding only a downhill path created (ie downhill at all points) ? I have a similar challenge and it would be great to hear if it is solved. We have been trying the Path Distance with Vertical Factors and a cost (friction) surface, but are not certain that we always get a downhill path created.